# Google Chrome change search engine prompt

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, search-engine, prompt

I'm wondering if anyone knows how DuckDuckGo trigger this prompt, i've had a little look through their source code and can see there is some `js`. but i don't know how they've done it.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

[image: DuckDuckGo Chrome Search Engine]

Answer (score 0):

It's a native way to add any search engine as the default one.
You can't access it by Javascript.

Comment: Any idea on this?